# reading behind from list

Tags: python, line

```
import numpy as np

filename = 'input1.txt'
output_file = 'output.txt'
delimiters = ',.?!'

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
for delimiter in delimiters:
    text = text.replace(delimiter, ',')
lines = text.split('\n')
parts = list()
print(lines)
```

I want all the lines containing text / numbers from the back to be in the sheet

example I have an input.text file

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
7,8,9,10,11,12
13,14,15,16,17
```

this give me

```
['1,2,3,4,5,6', '7,8,9,10,11,12', '13, 14,15,16,17 ',' ',' ',' ', '', '', '', '', '']
```

I'm looking for an exit from behind to read the lines

```
['13, 14,15,16,17', '7,8,9,10,11,12', '1,2,3,4,5,6', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't understand what you mean by "exit from behind". Do you mean that you want the results in reverse order? What is the "exit" part?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel `lines = text.split('\n')[::-1]`   this help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse a list in Python:

```
print(list('abc')[::-1])
> ['c', 'b', 'a']
```

Your case:

```
import numpy as np
import re
filename = 'input1.txt'
output_file = 'output.txt'
text = re.sub('[.?!]', ',', text)

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
text = re.sub('[.?!]', ',', text)

lines = text.split('\n')[::-1]
parts = []
print(lines)
```

Comment: text = re.sub('[.?!]', ',', text)
NameError: name 'text' is not defined. Did you mean: 'next'?

Comment: `import numpy as np

filename = 'input1.txt'
output_file = 'output.txt'
delimiters = ',.?!'

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
for delimiter in delimiters:
    text = text.replace(delimiter, ',')
lines = text.split('\n')[::-1]
parts = list()
print(lines)


print(lines[::-1])`  thanx  enough for this foundation I couldn't figure out how to use it